# Custom rqt plugin unable to load resource image

Tags: ros-kinetic, qt, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been following [this](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt/Tutorials/Create%20your%20new%20rqt%20plugin) tutorial on creating an rqt plugin.

I have designed the .ui file of the plugin in 'QT 4 Designer', and created the resources there.
My custom plugin contains a button with a background-image, styled as follows:

```
background: url(:/buttons/img/myImg.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
background-color:#1F1E24;
```

The image shows up in qt designer, but when I run it with `rosrun rqt_my_plugin rqt_my_plugin` the image does not show up.
The background color does however load, so the stylesheet is applied somehow.

When I enter an absolute path for the background url it works just fine, the generated relative path however does not.

Does anyone know the solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance!

**File structure**

```
src
└── (contents omitted)
srcipts
└── (contents omitted)
resource
├── myImages.qrc
├── myPlugin.ui
└── img
    └── myImg.png
```

**myImages.qrc**

```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="/buttons">
    <file>img/myImg.png</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

**myPlugin.ui (generated by QT 4 designer)**

```
 <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">background: url(:/buttons/img/myImg.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
                           background-color:#1F1E24;
       </string>
 </property>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/313032/custom-rqt-plugin-unable-to-load-resource-image/) by [Isha Dijcks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38758/isha-dijcks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 85 on 2019-01-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After a few tries I implemented a workaround where I set the url in the stylesheet programatically:

```
image_path = os.path.join(rospkg.RosPack().get_path('rqt_custom_plugin'), 'resource', 'img') + "myImg.png"

css_base = """
background: url(<img_path>) no-repeat center center;
background-color:#1F1E24;
"""
css = css_base.replace("<img_path>", img_path)

self._widget.my_button.setStyleSheet(css)
```

---

Originally posted by [Isha Dijcks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38758/isha-dijcks/) with karma: 85 on 2019-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0